# Problema con el cdn de datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

Buena noche tengo un problema, estoy tratando de utilizar el cdn de datatables y cuando quiero hacer una tabla no me carga las funciones de paginacion y búsqueda en la  datatable, y no tengo idea de cual es el problema aparece en este formato: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi es como se deberia de ver
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estos errores me salen en cosola cuando inspeciono

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que utilizo es este de la llamada de los cdn desde la pagina son:

```
<!--datatables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<!--bootstrap-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable();
} );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que tenes es claro,

> ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Se esta provocando porque en la línea 3

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Estas intentando cargar un plugin que es dependiente de [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) sin haberlo cargado previamente.

**¿La solución?**

Cargar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) antes de [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

```
<!--datatables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<!--bootstrap-->
....
.....
```

Comment: Gracias amigo efectivamente ese era el problema.